# onTap with Flutter plugin floating_frosted_bottom_bar

Tags: flutter, plugins, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am using the Flutter plugin floating_frosted_bottom_bar, and I want to display a page when the second item is clicked. I don't know how to do this. The code I have so far is this:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:floating_frosted_bottom_bar/floating_frosted_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'logo_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Frosted bottom bar',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Frosted bottom bar'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late int currentPage;
  late TabController tabController;

  final List<Color> colors = [
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.blue
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    currentPage = 0;
    tabController = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
    tabController.animation!.addListener(
      () {
        final value = tabController.animation!.value.round();
        if (value != currentPage && mounted) {
          changePage(value);
        }
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  void changePage(int newPage) {
    setState(() {
      currentPage = newPage;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FrostedBottomBar(
        opacity: 0.6,
        sigmaX: 5,
        sigmaY: 5,
        child: TabBar(
          indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 0, 6, 0),
          controller: tabController,
          indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 4),
            insets: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 8),
          ),
          tabs: [
            TabsIcon(
                icons: Icons.home,
                color: currentPage == 0 ? colors[0] : Colors.white),
            TabsIcon(
                icons: Icons.search,
                color: currentPage == 1 ? colors[1] : Colors.white),
            TabsIcon(
                icons: Icons.queue_play_next,
                color: currentPage == 2 ? colors[2] : Colors.white),
            TabsIcon(
                icons: Icons.file_download,
                color: currentPage == 3 ? colors[3] : Colors.white),
            TabsIcon(
                icons: Icons.menu,
                color: currentPage == 4 ? colors[4] : Colors.white),
          ],
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        hideOnScroll: false,
        body: (context, controller) => TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          children: colors
              .map(
                (e) => ListView.builder(
                  controller: controller,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return const Card(child: FittedBox(child: FlutterLogo()));
                  },
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TabsIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final IconData icons;

  const TabsIcon(
      {Key? key,
      this.color = Colors.white,
      this.height = 60,
      this.width = 50,
      required this.icons})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      child: Center(
        child: Icon(
          icons,
          color: color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkoOC.jpg

I am a beginner in Flutter so if you have a solution, please make it simple. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The image isn't accessible, post it in the question itself.

Comment: You can either paste/upload it directly into the question or use sites like Imgur to upload without making an account.

Comment: I uploaded it to Imgur and edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your code, Put your screens in List[Screens] only instead off ffff() , hope it helps.

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:floating_frosted_bottom_bar/floating_frosted_bottom_bar.dart';

import 'ffff.dart';
import 'hhkllj.dart';
// import 'logo_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Frosted bottom bar',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Frosted bottom bar'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int currentPage = 0;
  late TabController tabController;

  final List<Color> colors = [
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.blue
  ];
  List<Widget> Screens = [
    fff(),
    hhhhh(),
    fff(),
    hhhhh(),
    fff(),


  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
    tabController.animation!.addListener(
          () {
        final value = tabController.animation!.value.round();
        if (value != currentPage && mounted) {
          changePage(value);
        }
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  void changePage(int newPage) {
    setState(() {
      currentPage = newPage;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FrostedBottomBar(
        opacity: 0.6,
        sigmaX: 5,
        sigmaY: 5,
        child: TabBar(
          indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 0, 6, 0),
          controller: tabController,
          indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 4),
            insets: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 8),
          ),
          tabs: [
            TabsIcon(
                icons: Icons.home,
                color: currentPage == 0 ? colors[0] : Colors.white),
            TabsIcon(
                icons: Icons.search,
                color: currentPage == 1 ? colors[1] : Colors.white),
            TabsIcon(
                icons: Icons.queue_play_next,
                color: currentPage == 2 ? colors[2] : Colors.white),
            TabsIcon(
                icons: Icons.file_download,
                color: currentPage == 3 ? colors[3] : Colors.white),
            TabsIcon(
                icons: Icons.menu,
                color: currentPage == 4 ? colors[4] : Colors.white),
          ],
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        hideOnScroll: false,
        body: (context, controller) => Screens[currentPage]
        //     (context, controller) => TabBarView(
        //   controller: tabController,
        //   dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
        //   physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        //   children: colors.map(
        //         (e) => ListView.builder(
        //       controller: controller,
        //       itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        //         return const Card(child: FittedBox(child: FlutterLogo()));
        //       },
        //     ),
        //   )
        //       .toList(),
        // ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TabsIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final IconData icons;

  const TabsIcon(
      {Key? key,
        this.color = Colors.white,
        this.height = 60,
        this.width = 50,
        required this.icons})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      child: Center(
        child: Icon(
          icons,
          color: color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```